# Why does Eclipse keep undeploying my entire WAR file when I save a .xhtml file (in debug mode)?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, deployment

I am trying to just update a .xhtml file in debug mode, which has been working fine for months. Now, all of a sudden, Eclipse is deciding to undeploy my entire WAR file and re-deploy it, instead of just updating the .xhtml file instantly.

Is there a setting that somehow got changed accidently?

I'm using Eclipse 2019

Answer (score 0):

Go to Servers, right click, and then "publish". Not sure why this does anything differently, but it worked. Hot code replace works now.